# Run a logging filter in a separate thread - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, multiprocessing

I have a logging filter that checks for an environment variable to change and I want it to run (in the background) in a thread separate from the process that is setting the environment variable.

What I'm trying to do: every time logging.ERROR is called in my code, the user is alerted to the error and prompted on whether or not they want to continue.  Separately the filter and the prompt work correctly however, when I put them together I have a problem.  I need to have the filter running in the background so the code to prompt the user can run simultaneously (right now, the filter executes first and the prompt shows up after the `while` loop in the filter times out, at which point it is useless).

My filter code:

```
class ErrorFilter(logging.Filter):
  def __init__(self,level):
    self.level = level
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.filter,args=())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

  def filter(self,record):
    if record.levelno == self.level:
        os.environ["ERROR_FLAG"] = "True"
        timeout = time.time() + 60*1 #set the timeout to 1 minute
        while True:
            print "waiting..."
            keep_going = os.environ.get("CONTINUE_FLAG")
            #wait for user to respond
            if keep_going == "False" or time.time() > timeout:
                print "oops there's a problem, quitting."
                break
            if keep_going == "True":
                print "Continuing"
                break
        os.environ["CONTINUE_FLAG"] = "None"
```

I have another short method that "listens" for `ERROR_FLAG` and then asks for input using:

```
def continueAsk(message, title="Warning! Continue?", yn=("Yes","No")):
  yes = set(['yes','y', 'ye', '', 'canhaz'])
  no  = set(['no','n', 'lolzno'])

  tryLimit = 0
  while tryLimit < 100:
    sys.stdout.write(message + ": ")
    choice = raw_input().lower()
    if choice in yes:
        return True
    elif choice in no:
        return False
    else:
        tryLimit+=1
        sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no'.")
```

**EDIT**

I've also tried using `multiprocessing` in my filter like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
def __init__(self,level):
    self.level = level
    queue = Queue()
    p = Process(target=self.filter,args=("hi"))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I've tried setting up my filter so it runs in a different thread, but I've not had any luck so far (the filter still runs first, followed by the prompt) and I've never used multithreading before.  I know this is not a traditional use of the logger, but I appreciate any input on this.

Looking at the `subprocess` and `multiprocess` documentation, I think one of those might work as well but am not sure.